# Algorithm Comparison C#

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I am currently looking at typical interview questions, to get me in the right frame of mind.
I am trying to come up with my own solutions to the problems instead of trying to remember the given solutions.

The problem is that I'm not sure if my solutions are optimal or have a major flaw in design that i am not seeing.

So here is one of the solutions that I came up with for the basic "Is this string unique" problem as in check if all characters in a string are unique.

```
public static bool IsUnique(string str)
    {
        bool isUnique = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str.LastIndexOf(str.ElementAt(i)) != i)
            {
                isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isUnique;
    }
```

Does anyone have advice on whether this code is optimal and has acceptable time and space complexity?

Comment: Might be something for [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than code fixing.

Comment: Use `str[i]`.  Consider using a HashSet.

Comment: Depends on what you're going for - microoptimizing vs. readability. Readability, you can probably get away with `s.Length == s.Distinct().Count()`, but that's probably not microoptimized.

Comment: even though this only uses 1 for loop, it is still a **O(n^2)** algorithm.  this is because `elementAt` and `LastIndexOf` are **O(n)**.  Try putting the chars into some sort of dictionary and check for collisions

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. How do I move the post to the code review section or should I just re-post it there?

Comment: @SamIam that is another question I have. How do you know that 'elementAt' and 'LastIndexOf' are O(n)? As In does it say it somewhere in the msdn doc or do you just know from experience/looking at the method implementation

Comment: @user3071357 because it's impossible to do any better than **O(n)** when you're searching an unsorted list/array/string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer I will refer to Big-O notation to indicate complexity of an algorithm. The trick to efficiency is to realize the minimum Big-O measurement at which the problem can be solved, and then attempt to replicate that efficiency.

You can derive some efficiency facts by thinking about the algorithm logically: to check if all characters are unique, you need to evaluate all characters. So that's an O(n) traversal of the string guaranteed, and I doubt you'd easily get more efficient than that. Now, can you solve it yourself in O(n) or O(2n) time? If so, that's pretty decent because your algorithm is in **linear** time and will scale **linearly** (steadily get slower for larger string inputs).

Your current algorithm loops over the string and then for each character, iterates over the string again to compare it and find an equal character. This makes the algorithm an n traversal where each visit does an n traversal itself, so an O(n^2) algorithm. This is known as a **polynomial** time algorithm, which is not very good because it does not scale linearly; it scales **polynomially**. This means that your algorithm will get much slower with larger inputs, and that's a bad thing.

A quick change to make it slightly more efficient would be to start the comparison for an equivalent character at the current index you're at in the string + 1... You know that all previously checked characters are unique, so you care only about future characters. This would become an n traversal where each visit does a substring traversal from the current point (less work done as you traverse the string), but this is also an O(n^2) algorithm because it runs in the square of the outer loop's time. This is also a **polynomial** time algorithm, as before, but is slightly more efficient. It will still scale badly with larger inputs, however.

Think of alternative ways to avoid repeated iterations. These often come at the cost of memory, but are practical. I know how I would try and solve it, but telling you my answer doesn't help you learn. ;)

**EDIT: As you requested, I'll share my answer**

I'd do it by having a HashSet that I load each visited character into. HashSet lookups and adds are approximately an O(1) operation. The beauty of the HashSet.Add method is that it returns true if it added the value and false if the value already existed (which is the condition that determines your algorithm result). So mine would be:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<char>();
foreach (char c in myString)
{
    if (!hashSet.Add(c))
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

**Pros:** O(n) linear algorithm.

**Cons:** Extra memory used for HashSet.

**EDIT2: Everyone loves cheap LINQ tricks, so here's another way**

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<char>();
return myString.Any(c => !hashSet.Add(c));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I was thinking along those lines too. I was finding it hard to come up with a solution that had good complexity with the extra caveat that no other data structures could be used in the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah that makes much more sense starting the index 1 after the current index to avoid going through the entire string again.

Comment: If you want, I can share my solution with you as well as its pros and cons.

Comment: O(n^2) is polynomial.  O(2^n) would be exponential.

Comment: Also, factorial is exponential, so it is much worse than O(n^2), not better.

Comment: Ah very good, as there are no duplicates allowed in the HashSet.. happy days.

Comment: @mbeckish - thanks, I got mixed up. Updating.

Comment: @mbeckish - updated. Please verify that I classified the algorithms correctly this time.

Comment: No, now it is wrong in different ways.  For example, looping N times, with N operations per loop iteration is O(N^2), not O(N^N).

Comment: @mbeckish how about now, and if not, what Big O is the traversal with substrings? Clearly I'm rustier than I thought on my Big O. ;)... I think maybe it's O(n * 0.5n)?

Comment: @mbeckish  Factorial has a higher time complexity than exponential.

Comment: and **O(n^1.5)** id not exponential.  it is still just polynomial

Comment: @SamIam is my assessment of the second algorithm correct in terms of Big O?

Comment: @DavidHaney it is if you assume that reads of the hash-set are constant time.

Comment: Ahh, good. I do assume O(1) hash adds for this example, though in reality the .NET implementation *approaches* O(1).

Comment: You are wrong about your O(n^1.5) guess.  1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n is still O(n^2).

Comment: @mbeckish you're right, just verified it. Changing it one last time.

Comment: @SamIam - True.  Factorial is between 2^n and n^n.

Answer (score 0):

Using a HashSet is more efficient as it has a constant looup time O(1), compared to looking up a character in a string with a linear lookup time O(n):

```
public static bool AreCharsUnique(string str)
{
    var charset = new HashSet<char>();
    foreach (char c in str) {
        if (charset.Contains(c)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            charset.Add(c);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don't give them the answer: they want to know how to tell when they have the right answer, not what the right answer is.